# How to install Omnet++ 4.6 on windows

Tags: windows, omnet++

I would like to install Omnet++ 4.6 on my Windows 10 64 bits system and I'm not able to do it. First, I checked in the install guide pdf file on the website and it says to double click on mingwenv.cmd. I don't have this file in the folder I have downloaded but I have vcenv.cmd file (maybe they renamed the file)

To see what files are in omnet++ 4.6 zip folder : https://gyazo.com/2643c45b11f5346cd891efcfb9478787

I tried to run vcenv.cmd file a cmd window pop-up and close. I need to install this for my job and this could be appreciated if you could help me. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have downloaded linux version of OMNeT++. Download the package described as `OMNeT++ 4.6 win32 (source + IDE + MinGW, zip)`.